# Iterations of equations using sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x

To start off with I have two files, lets call them fileA and fileB.

In fileB I have two sequences, lets call them initial and final. Each sequences has exactly 32 values, most of which are simple equations that slightly differ from each other, hence the 32 unique values. For simplicity's sake let's scope them down to 5 each. so for initial it would look something like.

```
~fileB

T1 = 60

inital = [0.112, 0.233, 0.322*T1, 0.55*T1, 0.665*T1]
```

Variable T1 does not change at any point at all, So initial is constant permanently. The 2nd variable is called "final" 
For final I have:

```
T2 = 120

k_0 = T2**2 - T1**2

final =  [x * k_0 for x in initial]
```

This gives me the values I want for final and it gives me a sequence of the same length. In fileA I want to evalute an iterator at multiple T2 values and get an "answer" for each respective T2 value. However, since I am new, i'm limiting my self so that i'm only doing this for the very first final value.
So now on to fileA:

```
~fileA
import fileB
import math
answer = []
T2 = np.array(120,400,10)
x = symbols('x')
int1 = Integral(x**2 -1,x)
eq1 = int.doit()
for i in T2:
  k = k_0*final[0]
  answer.append(solve(eq1 - k, x))
```

This is where things get tricky, as i want it to evaluate this ONLY for the first "final" value

```
final[0]
```

but i want it to re-evaluate the two variables

```
 k_0 = T2**2 - T1**2
```

and

```
answer = []
```

At each and every T2 value, how can I do this so that I can make an array/table that looks like the following

```
T2 (header)    Answer(header)
value_1        Value_1
value_2        Value_2
value_3        Value_3
value_4        Value_4
....           ....
```

If you need me to explain it better of have questions feel free to ask.
If necessary i'm using python 3.6/3.7 in the anaconda distribution.

Comment: Judging by the complexity of this question I would wager that there is an easier way to get to what you want.  Can you try to frame this a little simpler and let us know what your overall goal is?

Comment: I will try my best next time i'm at work. I've only been learning python for about 2 weeks so i'm sure there are many things i'm familiar with right now. I'll get back to you soon, but unfortunately I think this is as simple as I can make it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay my question was a bit confusing but I figured out how to solve it.
The first step was to write a list comprehension for T2 instead of a np array, like so:

```
  T2 = [20 + x*1.01 +273.15 for x in range(40)]
```

Then I assigned the integral i wanted solved to a variable, let's call it int1.

```
int1 = Integral((1-x)**-2,x)
```

Then I have to create two new and separate empty sequences.

```
answer = []
X = []
```

For the first sequence (answer) I did the following:

```
for i,temp in enumerate(t2):
  k_0 = math.exp((ee/r)*((1/t1)-(1/t2[i]))) 
  k = initial_k[0]*k_0       
  v_0 = 2
  Fa_0 = 5
  Ca_0 = Fa_0/v_0
  Q = (k*Ca_0*V)/v_0
  eq1 = int1.doit()
  answer.append(solve(eq1 - Q,x))
```

While this will give the numerical answers I was looking for, each and every individual answer is returned as a sequence, which is inside of a sequence.

```
answer = [[value1],[value2],[value3],[value4]]
```

This causes problems when trying to use the numerical answers in other equations or operations.

To fix this i used the same technique as above and returned all of the numerical float values into a single sequence

```
for i,val in enumerate(answer):
  X.append(float(answer[i][0]))
```

This finally allowed me to use the numerical float values original stored in answer[] by simply transferring them to a new sequence where they are not nested.

```
Ca = [(1-x)*Ca_0 for x in X]
Fa = [(1-x)*Fa_0 for x in X]
```

Finally, I was able to get the table I originally wanted!

```
Temperature      Conversion             Ca                 Fa
```

---

```
 293.15 0.44358038322375287 1.3910490419406178 2.7820980838812357
 303.15 0.44398389128120275  1.390040271796993  2.780080543593986
 313.15 0.44436136324002395   1.38909659189994   2.77819318379988
 323.15  0.4447152402068642 1.3882118994828396 2.7764237989656793
```

I'm not completely sure why I had to do this but it worked, however, any help or insight into this would be appreciated.